# Package installation in Pycharm using Conda will not work

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, package, conda

This forum has helped me so much in the past months but now it was time to post something myself because this is the first problem i was not able to find an answer for. I would really appreciate any help i can get. I must mention that i am not an expert in python or programming, i have 3 months of intensive experience now and am working with python for my thesis on a uni computer with windows 7. I do not have any administrator rights so there will be some things i can not change.

I am using Pycharm 2018 with python 3.6 and anaconda 3.

For my project i need the netCDF4 and Basemap packages which are not already installed. However when i try to install these packages using Conda in the project interpreter settings i am not able to install any package. Even upgrading already installed packages gives the same problem. It gives me the following errors

> intallError : Error: one or more of the packages already installed depend on '>conda'
>
> Fetching package metadata .............
>   .Solving package specifications: .
>
> InstallError: Error: one or more of the packages already installed depend on 'conda'
>   and should only be installed in the root environment: conda conda-build conda-env
>   These packages need to be removed before conda can proceed.

I would really like your help, i already tried to install using pip in the console but this doesn't work because the pip version is 9 and the newest is 18. I am not an expert and could not find any solutions which might help so apart from pip i haven't really tried anything except the usual reinstalling of pycharm and rebooting. I have done the same on my laptop and everything worked fine, but my laptop is too slow to run the software properly so i need to use a uni pc.

Comment: Go to the Pycharm Terminal and type `conda install -c anaconda netcdf4 `. I have experienced trouble installing basemap a few weeks back. Try: `conda install -c conda-forge basemap` (also in the PyCharm terminal)

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interface for installing packages in the Settings of PyCharm does not work very well from my personal experience.

Safest and simplest way for beginners with Anaconda3 and PyCharm to install new packages is to use the embedded terminal within PyCharm.

Look up online, in the official website, which channel the package needs to be downloaded from (you can also see the most recent available version for your OS). The channel is the "place" it needs to download from. It is the argument we pass after the `-c` in the installation command.
Example: https://anaconda.org/anaconda/netcdf4

This webpage tells us to install the package using `conda install -c anaconda netcdf4` (from the `anaconda` channel)

When using the embedded PyCharm terminal, we do not need to worry about the environment in which the package needs to be installed. By default, it is installed in the environment chosen for the project.

Repeating the same process for basemap leads to use the following command to install it: `conda install -c conda-forge basemap` (This time it comes from the `conda-forge` channel.)

Edit: This answer assumes the user to use a conda environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command from the terminal:

```
conda update python-libarchive-c
```

Link to the issue on YouTrack:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-37293?_ga=2.28552767.2003633973.1575415101-1714842434.1573950593#focus=streamItem-27-3638791.0-0